# c# Посчитать количество элементов в цикле foreach

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. Нужно посчитать количество элементов по условию. Как можно это оформить красивее, без лишних переменных (например, elementsCount)?

Условие: Элементы находятся в коллекции, где есть несколько названий классов. Мне нужно посчитать только те классы, которые имеют название BaseWeapon.

```
    int elementsCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in items.Select(className => className.GetType().Name == nameof(BaseWeapon)).Where(result => result is true))
        elementsCount++;
    return elementsCount;
```

Нашёл вот такой вариант:

```
return items.Select(className => className.GetType().Name == nameof(MenuProductItemVm)).Where(result => result is true).Count();
```

Но возник вопрос, не будет ли долгим ожидание, если количество элементов будет больше 100000 и т.д.? Нужно ли здесь на разные потоки данный Linq. Насколько я помню, есть библиотека PLinq

Comment: Эквивалент вашему варианту `items.Count(item => item is MenuProductItemVm);`, только короче и быстрее.

Comment: `на разные потоки` вы время работы измерьте сначала, а потом рассуждайте о проблеме. Зачем решать то, что еще не случилось?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ